# wrong ordering in firefox for react order list having a nested unordered list

Tags: reactjs, list, firefox

I am havign a problem with the ordering of the list items in firefox, below is the code:

```
<ol>
  {
   Object.keys(rules).map((key) => {
   if (typeof rules[key] === 'string') {
      return <li key={key}>{rules[key]}</li>
    } else if (typeof rules[key] === 'object') {
       const nested = rules[key].subList
       return (
         <ul key={key}>
         {
           Object.keys(nested).map((key) => {
            return <li key={key}>{nested[key]}</li>
           })
         }
         </ul>
       )
      }
     })
   }
</ol>
```

The output of the code is

```
 1. first
 2. second:
  . option
  . another option
 5. third
 6. fourth
```

But the desired output is:

```
 1. first
 2. second:
   . option
   . another option
 3. third
 4. fourth
```

I know the problem is the unordered list should be nested under the second list item but is there a way to simply modify the current code to achieve the desired result?

Input json is:

```
"rules": {
  "list": [
    "first",
    "second:",
    {
      "subList": [
        "option",
        "another option"
      ]
    },
    "third",
    "fourth"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here is the workaround which worked for me:

First, I have to change the structure of JSON a little bit, like this:

```
"rules": {
  "list": [
    "first",
    {
      "second": [
        "option",
        "another option"
      ]
    },
    "third",
    "fourth"
  ]
}
```

and then some modifications to code as well

```
<ol>
  {
   Object.keys(rules).map(key => {
     if (typeof rules[key] === 'object') {
        const nested = rules[key]
        return Object.keys(nested).map(mkey => {
          return <li key={key}>{mkey}:<ul>
            {
              Object.keys(nested[mkey]).map(nkey => {
                return <li key={nkey}>{nested[mkey][nkey]}</li>
              })
            }
          </ul></li>
        })
      } else {
        return <li key={key}>{rules[key]}</li>
      }
    })
   }
</ol>
```